# timeout for individual test using Nunit

Tags: nunit

is there any way to implement timeout option for individual tests in a bunch of test executed on the ccnet.

Mbunit and MSTest have [Timeout] attribute.

I am looking for similar feature in Nunit.

This is to avoid long running tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of nUnit are you using?  The most recent version (2.5 Beta) has a [Timeout](http://www.nunit.com/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5) attribute.

Comment: FYI - nunit 2.5 is in release now. http://nunit.com/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5